# Why am I getting FFMPEG "cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)" error?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming, alsa

I'm trying to stream audio input from Seeed Studio 4-Mic-Array Respeaker on desired IP address and port on Raspberry Pi 4.

Command that I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -ac 4 -ar 16000 -f rtp rtp://10.0.0.1:1234
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)
```

Result from `arecord --dump-hw-params -D hw:1,0` command is:

```
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
HW Params of device "hw:1,0":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S32_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: 128
CHANNELS: 4
RATE: [8000 48000]
PERIOD_TIME: (333 2048000]
PERIOD_SIZE: [16 16384]
PERIOD_BYTES: [256 262144]
PERIODS: [2 2048]
BUFFER_TIME: (666 4096000]
BUFFER_SIZE: [32 32768]
BUFFER_BYTES: [512 524288]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
arecord: set_params:1299: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

Comment: Try `-c:a pcm_s32le` input option.

Comment: @llogan Your advice work when I change positions of some parameters. Thank you. Following command is working `ffmpeg -re -f alsa -c:a pcm_s32le -ac 4 -ar 16000 -i hw:1,0 -f rtp_mpegts rtp://10.0.0.1:1234`. On receiving side when I play the stream with VLC player it isn't continuous, it have breaks every 2 seconds. What can I do to make it more stable?

Comment: Should be asked as a new question (ask at [su] as Stack Overflow is supposed to be for programming questions so it might get closed here).